# Analogies and differences between polynomial evaluation and modulo operations

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, big-picture

Given a polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$, prime $p$ and integer $a$ are there analogies and differences between evaluating $f(x)$ at $x=a$ and computing $a\bmod p$? Both look like some kind of function evaluation.

Comment: Do you know what $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb Z$ is?

Comment: @PseudoNeo I have seen the notation.

Comment: Basically, for every ring $A$, there is something called the *spectrum* of $A$, $\mathrm{Spec}\, A$, such that any element of $A$ can be seen as a kind of function on $A$. For a field $K$, $\mathrm{Spec}\, K[X]$ is not far from being $K$, and the "evaluation" at $x$ is the true evaluation. For $\mathbb Z$, $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb Z$ is not far from being the set of primes, and the "evaluation" at $p$ is the reduction modulo $p$. (You see a subtlety: an element of $A$ is a kind of function on $A$, but the "values" this "function" takes at different points live in different sets.)

Comment: At a more elementary level, all of this comes from the fact that $\mathfrak m_{x_0} = (X-x_0) K[X]$ is a maximal ideal of $K[X]$, and $p \mathbb Z$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z$, and the two maps you're talking about can be seen as the canonical maps $K[X] \to K[X]/\mathfrak m_{x_0} \simeq K$ and $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.